# Как определить какого рода топонимы?

Tags: существительные

Мой вопрос следующий, как можно определить какого рода топоним. Почему, например, город Аккра женского рода, а город Палермо мужского? какими правилами пользоваться?

Answer (score 1):

Палермо расположен, прекрасный  Палермо. Для **несклоняемого** топонима мужской род выбран по слову "город".

Аккра расположена, прекрасная Аккра. Топоним **на безударный А** в разных текстах может склоняться по 1-му склонению (как сущ. ж.р.), но может и не склоняться, при этом его род меняется:

(1) современный Аккра (город), в современном Аккра и современная Аккра/в современной Аккре (склоняемый топоним).

**Дополнение:**

1) **Государство (ср.р.)** Северное Борнео (англ. North Borneo) с 1892 по 1946 годы было британским протекторатом, управляемым Британской компанией Северного Борнео.

2) Город Сочи был основан 21 апреля 1838 как форт Александрия,  с 1896 — Сочи (по названию реки Сочи, на берегах которой стоял посад). **Топоним не склоняется и относится к м.р (город).** Новый Сочи - микрорайон в составе Центрального района. **Новый Сочи (м.р.)** обладает развитой инфраструктурой.

3) Бешта́у (с карачаево-балкарского беш — пять и тау — гора) — изолированная пятиглавая гора — лакколит, высочайшая из 17 останцовых магматических гор Пятигорья на Кавказских Минеральных Водах. Высота 1400 м. Памятник природы. Осенний Бештау (м.р) - это всегда невероятно красочно. Горы Большой Бештау, Малый Бештау. Топоним не склоняется, **возможно, м.р. связан с понятием "горный массив".** Но: Гора Бештау (ж.р.) прекрасна в любое время года.

4) В современном Осака (нескл. м.р.) и в современной Осаке (склон. сущ. на А, ж.р. ). **Ассоциаций никаких, одна грамматика**.

Answer (score 0):

Можно пользоваться общим правилом:

род несклоняемых иноязычных географических названий определяется по родовому нарицательному слову,

в нашем случае - по слову "город", то есть никогда не будет ошибкой обозначить Палерму и Аккру лицами мужескаго полу, но с Аккрой - дополнительное правило-нюанс: ложная аналогия с любой икрой, по созвучию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более полные объяснения вряд ли себя обнаружат.

Comment: Вот только "Палерму" не надо )))

Comment: Пачиму нэ нада?! Я всё склоняю - планида моя, видать, такая... )))

Comment: Потому, что он - Палерм**о**. Был бы Палерма, было бы ещё понятно. А Палермо - как Буратино или Хулио. В русском не склоняется. Не украинский, чай. )))

Comment: Забыл. А Осло склонять не пробовали? Или Катманду?

Comment: Да я всё-все склоняю: в пальте, в метре, в Осле, в Катманде... и, что небезынтересно: меня понимают! ))) Я по тугаменту и по жизни редактор - мне простительно!